# Laravel script stops running after some time

Tags: command-line, laravel

I have this php script that runs for quite a while but after some time (due to browser limit when it stops loading the page) it stops with executing the code.

Basically what it does is fetch 10000 articles using an API and store them one-by-one in my own DB. After looping roughly 1200+ articles, the Google Chrome spinning/loading icon stops and all I get back in return is a blank page. When I check the DB I can see the results in the DB, but however the script didn't loop through all the articles as it should and it stopped.

I know running from CLI would remove the default browser-time-limit when it stops loading, but I don't know **how to make a call to a certain controller method in Laravel from command line**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in fact seeding a database, a **quick and dirty** way is to use db:seed to do it for you:

```php
class MyTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {

            // Do whatever you need to

    }

}
```

Enable it on DatabaseSeeder:

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('MyTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

And execute it:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

A much better way is to create an Artisan Command. Here's another answer I wrote to teach how to create it: [Select all rows with a date of right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304071/select-all-rows-with-a-date-of-right-now/19305460#19305460)

Comment: Yeah haha, but seeding would be kind of cheating here.
I guess making an Artisan command and move the code from the controller to a command would be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, if it's a one time thing, you cheat to get things done is allright, but if you gonna use that everyday, Artisan Command is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah it's actually supposed to be a cron-job script.

Comment: That answer I wrote has info about cron too. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Make an Artisan command. See the docs at http://laravel.com/docs/commands

Comment: I have checked out that link already but apparently there is no way I can make a call to a specific **controller** method. You could basically only access models from what I have understood.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove timeout limit from the web server(mostly from the config file)
2. Use `set_time_limit(0)` to force PHP to execute your code for unlimited amount of time.

Comment: I have done this, and this removed the PHP error when it reaches maximum execution time of 30 seconds.

But this isn't a PHP error, I don't get any errors anymore, the code is running fine. This is a browser-thing where it just stops after a certain time.

I have done the same thing but when programming procedural and via browser I would get the same error, but when doing it from command line the script would finish it work. Now that I am doing it through Laravel, I need to know how to make a call to a controller method via command line.

Comment: @ToniPerić This might sound like a hack, but have you tried requesting the route to your class/method from the command-line then saving it in a text file? For example(on wget-installed Linux systems) `wget http://example.com/{route_to_method} > output.txt`

Comment: Good thought, I already have tried it and it's not working unfortunately.
Thanks for the effort though!

What I could do is simply move all the code from the controller to a command-line but then I'll have the same code at two places. Redundancy issue.